# Animation attached to objects instead of Armature?

Tags: animation

I don't understand why a few of my animations are showing up under objects in the NLA editor instead of the armature. I don't know how I messed this up or what the implications are.

Any wisdom is greatly appreciated! [image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably assigned animation **Action** to these objects.

If you switch to **Dope Sheet** editor and in header switch from Dope Sheet to **Action Editor** - there you can assign any animation (listed) to what ever object you have selected.

[image]

Comment: If this is not your case, you should attach simplified blend, only with one issue example to let as discover more (https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).